# Magento 2 category as a static page

Tags: category, cms, magento2.2.3

In Magento 2, I want One Category as a static page.

I don't want any products or filter or toolbar in it. Just need to load the content from the static block.

In, short I wanted to make one category as Static Page.

Can anyone suggest me the idea to do so?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a static block under `Contents -> Blocks` which you need to show on the category page.
2. Now Go to the Category edit section under `Catalog -> Categories` for which you need to show the static block.
3. In category edit section, under the tab `Display Settings`, set `display mode` as the `static block only` and set the `anchor` to `no`.

[image: category-display-settings]

4. Now under the tab `content`, select the static block that you have created in step1 from the `add cms block` drop-down.

[image: category-static-block]

5. If you want to change the layout to 1 column, then select `1column` from `layout` drop-down under the `design` tab.
6. Save.

I hope you will get some idea from the shared steps for your requirement.

Comment: I did the same but static block not showing in category page.

Comment: @KaushalSuthar Check code, if there is any related modification which is causing the issue.